# Azure Automation: The term 'Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan' is not recognized

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to scale up a service plan using `Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan`. I'm connecting fine, can list all the resources in the account but when calling the app plan method, it isn't found.  What is being missed here?

Code:

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId "MYSUB"

Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "my-plan" -ResourceGroupName "my-group" -Tier "Standard" -WorkerSize "Small"
```

Error:

```
Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan : The term 'Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
At line:35 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "JJJLK" -ResourceGroupN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-AzureRmAppServicePlan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: I saw that but for some reason it didnt register or I didn't see the import under assets. Maybe need to look when I'm not so tired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need import the appropriate modules into your Azure Automation Account. You could import modules from Automation Module Gallery with the Azure Portal.

[image]

More information please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41218196/get-azurermappserviceplan-and-get-azurermwebapp-return-exceptions-in-runbook).

Also you could import the module by the [link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.Websites/2.4.0).

[image]

Wait for a moment, you could find the two cmdlet in Portal.

[image]

Comment: `Automation Accounts`-->`SHARED Resources`-->`Modules`

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize it could be done with a button click. I love the fact the the azure team is moving so quickly but it makes the documentation found on the internet out of date sometimes!